# how to call ajax function from controller...in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i need to create country drop down list in codeigniter. onchange event im calling a  another controller of project thats name is ajax.php i need to know that how to get url and send data to url in codeigniter.

my ajax function is

```
var base_url = "<? echo base_url()?>";

        function getstate(value) {

                if (value !== '') {

                  //alert('test');

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url:base_url+"adminzone/ajax/ajax.php",
                        data: "do=getstate&value=" + value,
                        success: function(msg) {

                            alert(msg);

                            //$('#psid').html("<img src='images/spacer.gif'>");

                            $('#reg1').html(msg);


                            //

                            //$('#sid').sSelect({ddMaxHeight: '300px'});

                        },
                        error: function() {
                            //alert('some error has occured...');
                        },
                        start: function() {
                            //alert('ajax has been started...');    
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

my ajax controller is

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

//error_reporting(0); class ajax extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        if (!$this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in')) {

            redirect('adminzone');
        }
        $this->load->model('doctor_model');
    }

    public function getstate(){
        echo $this->input->post();exit;
    }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

ajax function in view

```
  $('#countryfield').change(function() {
        var passedvalue = $('#countryfield').val();
        var path = base_url+"ajax/getState";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: path,
            data: {'passedvalue': passedvalue},
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    alert(success);//task done on success
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                    alert('some error occurred');
                },
          });
      })
```

Now you can write function in ajax.php controller .
name of function should be getState

```
     public function getstate(){
       echo $this->input->post('passedvalue'); //now here you can perform your task
         exit;
       }
```

Now you can perform your task in controller and echo the value that you want to pass to the view.